# Probability of winning a match given probability of winning a game

Tags: probability

If a team has probability p of winning each game, and if the team wins/loses a match when it is 2 games ahead/behind the other team, is there an analytical formula or approximation for the probability that the team wins the match, as a function of p? One can of course resort to Monte Carlo. Here is what I tried:

```
p = prob of A winning each game
p1 = prob of A winning when match tied
p2 = prob of A winning when ahead by 1 game
p3 = prob of A winning when behind by 1 game

p1 = p*p2 + (1-p)*p3 = p*p2 + p3 - p*p3
p2 = p + (1-p)*p1    = p + p1 - p*p1
p3 = p*p1 + 1 - p    = p*p1 + 1 - p

plug last into first:

p1 = p*p2 + (1-p) * (p*p1 + 1 - p)

plug 2nd into above

p1 = p*(p + p1 - p*p1) + (1-p) * (p*p1 + 1 - p)
   = p^2 + p*p1 - p^2*p1 + p*p1 + 1 - p - p^2*p1 - p + p^2

p1 = (2*p^2 - 2*p + 1)/(2*p^2 - p + 1)
```

But for `p=0`, this gives `p1=1`, which is wrong.

Comment: Is each game independent of the results in the others? If so, then yes.  What have you tried?

Comment: Yes @Henry, the games are independent. I updated the question to show what I tried.

Comment: Your error is in "$p_3 = p\times p_1 + 1 - p$" since you lose the match when two games behind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way to do the calculation is to note that you win two in a row, or you lose two in a row, or you start again.

So the probability is $p_1= \dfrac{p^2}{p^2+(1-p)^2}= \dfrac{p^2}{2p^2-2p+1}$.

Let's try it your way:

- $p_1=p\times p_2+(1-p)\times p_3$
- $p_2=p\times 1+(1-p)\times p_1$
- $p_3=p\times p_1+(1-p)\times 0$ though you seem to have missed the $\times 0$

so substituting the second and third into the first and tidying up gives

$$p_1 = p^2 \times 1 +p(1-p)\times p_1+ (1-p)p \times p_1 + (1-p)^2\times 0$$
$$p_1 (1-2p(1-p))= p^2 $$
$$p_1 = \dfrac{p^2}{1-2p(1-p)}  = \dfrac{p^2}{1-2p+2p^2}$$ which is the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Since Wimbledon is on, we could well model the game as being at deuce, and compute the probability of your winning the game as an exact parallel !

Then taking your winning probability for a point as $p$, losing as $q (=1-p)$, from deuce $d$ you either win two consecutive points or win/lose one point each to return to deuce

Thus $d = p^2 +2pq*d$

which yields $d = \Large\frac{p^2}{1-2pq}$

Comment: Yes, actually the question was motivated by tennis.

Comment: @Fortranner: Then you should be happy at this answer ! $\;\;$ :)